# OpenSMILE : using the voice-activity detector (vad)

Tags: audio, feature-extraction

I'm new with OpenSMILE and i would like to use the voice-activity detector wich is given at download.

But when i follow the tutorial and launch openSMILE with the following command line :

```
SMILExtract -C config/vad_opensource.conf -I sample/Test3.wav -O Try3.csv
```

i get this error (twice) :

```
(ERROR) [1] in configManager : ConfigType::findFieldH: referenced base field with name 'selectedRange' not found!
```

I checked in the config file and selectedrange is in it so i don't understand the problem and since there are not so much people using openSMILE i couldn't fine any answer on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind late for you. But I will post the answer here anyway in case others need it.

You will have to manually change into the directory contain the config file for it to work:

`cd some_dir/scripts/vad`;
and then `SMILExtract -C vad_opensource.conf -I some_dir/Test3.wav -O Try3.csv`

(Source:http://records.mlab.no/2015/01/05/opensmile-the-munich-open-source-large-scale-multimedia-feature-extractor-a-tutorial-for-version-2-1/)